# jQuery Colour Animation

Tags: jquery, colors, jquery-animate, tumblr

I'm stuck with a function that doesn't want to animate...

I'm using the latest [jQuery Color Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) to enable color animations. Now, what should happen in the following code is that (when it works of course):

(1) the user selects a colour, 
(2) based on the RGB value of that colour we create a lighter shade of that color, 
(3) when hovering over a link, it's colour is replaced by the newly calculated colour, 
(4) when moving off the link, the original colour should be animated in.

The colour substitution work absolutely fine, but the animation doesn't as it currently looks more like a traditional CSS hover effect than one done over 800msecs with jQuery.

If the Ninja's out there can help me out, I'd be more than willing to shine your throwing stars for a week :). Here's the code:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
//code when hover over
$oldColour = $(this).css('color');

    $(this).animate({'color': $(this).css('color', function(i, v){
      var rgb = getRGB($(this).css('color'));

      for(var i = 0; i < rgb.length; i++){
        rgb[i] = (rgb[i] + 60 < 255) ? rgb[i] + 60 : 255;
      }

      var newColor = 'rgb(' + rgb[0] + ',' + rgb[1] + ',' + rgb[2] + ')';
      return  newColor;

      }) //end anonymous function
    }, 800); //end animate


    }, function() {
      //code when hovering away
      $(this).animate({'color': $(this).css('color', $oldColour)}, 800);
    });
```

Your help, as always, is awesome and greatly appreciated!
Thank yous (and girls, of course) for taking a look :)

PS To see a live example, go to [demo page](http://tinygiantstudios.tumblr.com/) and hover over any link...

===== UPDATE: And more Help needed =====
Cambraca's code underneath works perfectly. Except that in IE it first fades to a very dark colour, then returns to the initial colour when I mouse off, and then when I hover over it again, the correct recalculated colour displays...

Any ideas on how to solve this for IE?

Comment: Why do you need `$(this).css('color', function...`?

Comment: Truthfully, I busted my balls in inserting that function(i, v) straight after the animate color section - it just wouldn't run, so I came up with the css color function :). Clearly it didn't work, but I was at my wits end... Spent more than 3 hours trying to come up with a solution before turning to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var $oldColour;

$('a').hover(function() {
    //code when hover over
    $oldColour = $(this).css('color');
    var rgb = getRGB($(this).css('color'));
    for (var i = 0; i < rgb.length; i++)
        rgb[i] = Math.min(rgb[i] + 60, 255);
    var newColor = 'rgb(' + rgb[0] + ',' + rgb[1] + ',' + rgb[2] + ')';
    $(this).animate({'color': newColor}, 800);
}, function() {
    //code when hovering away
    $(this).animate({'color': $oldColour}, 800);
});
```

Comment: Yeeeehaaaaaa! Bring on over your ninja throwing stars, I'd be happy to give 'em a polish... Thanks Cambraca, much appreciated :)

Comment: Hmm, as usual, this works perfectly in every browser except IE - any idea why?

Comment: Damn... maybe the getRGB function? maybe put alerts between each line so it tells you how much actually runs. I hate IE...

Comment: I think I might have found IE's issue. On the first run, IE uses the HEX value to convert the colour, thereafter, once you hover over the link again, it uses the RGB value... Do you happen to have a handy HEX = RGB converter? Anyways, I've put in a bunch of console.logs for every stage of the mouseover event if you wanna check it out :)

Comment: I continued this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262417/jquery-hex-to-rgb-calculation-different-between-browsers     - Over there you can see the getRGB function as well as a detailed walkthru of how I think the code should work. Funny thing is, in IE, it only gets the colour wrong on the first hover, thereafter, it works perfectly.

Comment: @cambraca, with the help at icyrock, we managed to solve the problem - if you're interested, the link I mentioned above has the answer :)