# Search and replace hexadecimal color codes with rgb values in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, color-codes

I have the HTML source of an element. I want to search all the hexadecimal color codes in it and replace them with their RGB equivalents. How can I do that using JavaScript?

E.g.:

```
This is <span style="color:#FF0000">red</span> and <span style="color:#3C9310">green</span> color.
```

should be replaced with

```
This is <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0)">red</span> and <span style="color: rgb(60, 147, 16)">green</span> color.
```

Comment: These styles only occur in spans? And is that the only style you define inline, for the spans?

Comment: @Cerbrus colors can be in any element (span/div/table etc..). And yes, I want to change only inline definitions.

Comment: Look here to convert hexa to rgb: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4262484/1414562

Comment: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm

Comment: So you want JavaScript to loop through all DOM elements. May I ask why you need this?

Comment: This shouldn't be done at run time. It will be to slow.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this? Firstly inline css is bad practice and secondly it just doesn't matter, the color will be the same either way. I don't see the point I guess...

Comment: @Cerbrus I am working on a persistant Text highlighter script in jQuery using mysql database. I am loading the marked selections by user by storing them in DB. But IE renders the hex color values as RGB. So I cannot do a search and replace thing with the HTML source in IE. Although all other browsers are happy with it. Hope you get my point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to convert all hex colours into decimal RGB values in the string `str`, the following will do the trick. Note that this only considers 8-bit/channel hex values (e.g., `#FF0000`) and not the 4-bit variants (e.g., `#F00`); however, this would be easy enough to enhance.

```
var rgbHex = /#([0-9A-F][0-9A-F])([0-9A-F][0-9A-F])([0-9A-F][0-9A-F])/gi
str.replace(rgbHex, function (m, r, g, b) {
  return 'rgb(' + parseInt(r,16) + ','
                + parseInt(g,16) + ','
                + parseInt(b,16) + ')';
})
```

Comment: this is just awesome. This is what I was searching for. Thanks a lot dude...

Comment: @Arvind07: Are you really going to `string.replace` your code snippets with a `RegEx`? That could get rather heavy on the browser.

Comment: @Cerbrus The string is not very long. I think it will not be very heavy to make a regex replace. Also I have string available to work with, not the actual HTML element. So it seems Ok to me. Your suggestions are always welcomed...

Comment: @Arvind07: Ah, I see.
Fair enough, then ^_^

Answer (score 5):

You can use jquery `css('color')`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n33BK/)**

```
$('#spcolor').css('color')
```

For iterating through many elements have same class.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n33BK/1/)**

```
$('.someclass').each(function(){
   alert($(this).css('color'))    
});
```

Comment: It was so easy but I did not figure that out. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: No worries, some time we miss the simple and each solutions...

Comment: You might want to mention using `'*'` as a selector to loop through all elements.

Answer (score 2):

Using [the function shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262417/jquery-hex-to-rgb-calculation-different-between-browsers/4262484#4262484), you can change the colour property of all elements on the page that have it set from Hex to RGB:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var elemCount = all.length;

for (var i=0; i < elemCount; i++) {
    if(all[i].style.color && all[i].style.color.indexOf('#') > -1){ //Check if the color property is set, and if it's hex.
        all[i].style.color = hex2rgb(all[i].style.color)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. Would probably look cleaner the jQuery way, but the logic is the same.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks for the answer. Its really easy to understand and implement.

Comment: @JuannStrauss: It would possibly look cleaner, yes, but it will also be a lot slower in jQuery.
For something like this: short code but a large loop, I prefer to use native JS...
Arvind07: In that case, please consider marking this as your answer, if it works for you ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
rgbval = "rgb("
"#ff0000".replace(/[a-z0-9]{2}/g, function(val) {rgbval  += (parseInt(val, 16)) + ","})
rgbval  += ")"
```

The will add an extra comma at the end like rgb(255,0,0,) but i think you can remove it.